# Tracking Multi-page Forms in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an order form that's several pages long, where users can input quantities of items. I'm trying to keep a running total of the order total.

https://jsfiddle.net/kodemonki/9vj98u9m/3/

Here's the bulk of the code I've been working with. You can see some of what I've tried.

```
 function recalculate(){
    var qtyArray = new Array();
    var costArray = new Array();
    var total_cost = 0;

    // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
    // $('input[type="number"].part_qty').each(function(){
    //  // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
    //  if(!$.contains(document, this)){
    //      // Create a hidden element 
    //      $(form).append(
    //          $('<input>')
    //              .attr('type', 'hidden')
    //              .attr('name', this.name)
    //              .val(this.value)
    //              .attr('class','part_qty')
    //      );
    //  } 
    // });

    //$('input[type=number].part_qty').each(function(){
    $('input[type=number]').each(function(){
        qtyArray.push(Number($(this).val()));
        //console.log(this);
    });
    $('.part_cost').each(function(){
        costArray.push(Number($(this).html().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")));

    });

    for(var i = 0;i < qtyArray.length; i++){
        // console.log(qtyArray[i] + isNaN(qtyArray[i]));
        // console.log(costArray[i] + isNaN(costArray[i]));
        total_cost = total_cost + (qtyArray[i] * costArray[i]);
        //console.log(total_cost);
    }   

    total_cost = Math.round(total_cost*100)/100;

    var table = $('#partsList').DataTable();
    var data = table.$('input').serialize();
    // console.log(data);   

    //console.log(qtyArray);
    //console.log(costArray);
    //$(#order_total).html('32532');
    $("#order_total").html('$'+total_cost);
}
```

Not sure why pagination or the total isn't showing up in the Fiddle. It looks fine on my dev site.

However, I can't get the total to keep track across pages. I've looked at several solutions and can't seem to get it. For form submission I added the removed data back in, but the same solution doesn't seem to work for the totals.

Thank you.